# Is there a way to replace <img> tags with alternate text in selectedText property of QML TextEdit

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have a `TextEdit` component used to show text messages. When parsing messages I replace common emoticons shortcuts with emojis using `<img>` tag and setting `textFormat: TextEdit.RichText` on my `TextEdit` component. When somebody copies a message containing an emoji, `selectedText` attribute of `TextEdit` inserts an OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER 0xFFFC instead of selected `<img>` tag.

Example:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2


Item {
    id: root
    width: 500
    height: 500

    TextEdit {
        id: myTextEdit

        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Test <img src=\"app.icns\"></img> image"
        textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
        readOnly: true
        selectByMouse: true

        onSelectedTextChanged: {
            console.log(selectedText);
        }
    }
}
```

When you select everything inside of the `myTextEdit` it prints "Test ￼ image". Is there a way to specify some other way of replacing `<img>` in `selectedText` so I can choose some alternate text instead of 0xFFFC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` to get the actual text in that range from `text` instead of relying on the value of `selectedText`.

Something like:

```
    console.log(text.slice(selectionStart, selectionEnd));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Already tried that, but it is not enough. For example if there is this message "Hello :D Friend", it would be rendered with an emoticon <img> instead of ":D". If a person would then select word "Hello" and the emoji, selectionStart would be 0, selectionEnd would be 7 (since it counts the selected <img> tag as 1 character). Slicing from 0 to 7 would give me "Hello :". There are emoticon shortcuts with 3 characters, or the selection could be in the middle, and all that creates more issues with tracking of selection indexes.

Comment: So, text selection is in terms of the visible elements, not the source text, eh? Then it seems like you'll need to generate and keep track of a data structure that maps from what the selection looks like where <img> references = 1 character back to the original source you fed into the control with the actual <img> tags.